# How to get total pv created for all of User's Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a simple models:

```
class Pv(models.Model):
accounts =(
    ('Sub CF','Sub CF'),
    ('Special','Special'),
    ('Directors','Directors'),
    ('Operations','Operations'),
    ('LSGDP','LSGDP'),
    ('DWAP','DWAP'),
    ('Capacity(USD)','Capacity(USD)')
    )
acc =(
('Yes','Yes'),
('No', 'No')
)

source =(
        ('GOG','GOG'),
        ('Others', 'Others')
      )
pv =(
    ('General','General'),
    ('Honorarium','Honorarium')
   )
center=(
    ('Cost Center 1','Cost Center 1'),
    ('Cost Center 2','Cost Center 2'),
    ('Cost Center 3','Cost Center 3'),
    ('Cost Center 4','Cost Center 4'),
    ('Cost Center 5','Cost Center 5')
       )
stat =(
    ('Completed','Completed'),
    ('Returned','Returned'),
    ('Cancelled','Cancelled')
)
IA_System_Code = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
IA_code = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
Date_recieved = models.DateField()
Pv_reference = models.CharField(unique = True, max_length = 120)
Source_of_Funding = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = source)
Cost_center = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = center)
Payee = models.CharField(max_length=500)
Description = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
Account_code = models.CharField(max_length=350)
Gross_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
Withholding_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
Net_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
Status = models.CharField(max_length = 60, choices = stat )
Remarks =models.CharField(max_length = 500, blank = True)
Acc_Impress = models.CharField(max_length = 350,choices=acc)
Date_returned =models.DateField(null=True,blank = True)
Type_of_accounts= models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = accounts)
Type_of_pv = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices = pv)
returned_to_chest = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
created = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
created_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', blank=True, null=True,\ 
                               default=None,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='create')
modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
modified_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', blank=True, null=True,\
                                 default=None ,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='modified')
class Meta():
        ordering = ["IA_System_Code"]



def __str__(self):
    return self.Description

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = get_current_user()
    if user and not user.pk:
        user = None
    if not self.pk:
        self.created_by = user
        self.created = datetime.now()
    else:
        self.modified_by = user
        self.modified = datetime.now()
    super(Pv, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'm struggling to figure out, what I think should be a simple query, with Django's ORM.

Let's say I have a total of 6 PV created by 3 unique Users Now, what I really want is to query all pv and count the pvs created by each User, but only want one of each unique User and add a (what I think should be an annotated) property called total to each User. i dont also want to display users in the system who have not made any pv entry.

So if the User has 2 PV created , his total will be 2. please can anybody help me out .
How do i display it on my template as a table.
example :

```
   user   total pv recorded for the yr
   John       10
   peter      20
   pack        5
```

please can anyone help me out . looks like i dont know what am doing. thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this query. 
**views.py**

```
 from django.db.models import Count, Q # import Q here
 import datetime
 today = datetime.datetime.now()
 qry = User.objects.filter(Q(create__isnull=False) & Q(create__created__year=today.year)).\
       annotate(counter=Count('create')).\
       prefetch_related('create') # this will only count the PV s from current yaer
```

send `qry` in template

**template**

```
{% for i in qry %}
{% if i.counter != 0 %} # checking if PV exist for user
# edited line
<p>{{ i.first_name }} {{ i.counter }}</p> # first name number of PVs

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I hope this helps.

**Edit**

You can print anything you want. {{ j.description }} is for example. I have edited the code. Current code will print fisrt_name and counte (john 5). you can replace first_name with any like **first_name last_name count**, or you have defined **name** in model.
**Edited**
 i edited your query so it's now counting only those users who have only registered a pv. now i need reset the counter to zero when ever a new year start

Comment: your code works but need to have the user then the total. eg john 10

Comment: i dont need to display the description too.

Comment: your code works but need to have the user's fullname then the total. eg john 10

Comment: {{ j.Description }} is for example. you can print anything you want there. @TERKPEHMENSAH

Comment: the code works perfectly now except it also brings out the users who have also not  registered any pv and is there a way i can make make i.counter =0 if we enter into a new year . example john has 20 in year 2020 but if we enter into 2021 john's count should reverse to 0 and start the counting all over again. thank u

Comment: @TERKPEHMENSAH, 1) this will not print user with 0 count. I have edited the code.

Comment: @TERKPEHMENSAH, You want to delete PVs of previous year or just want to the number of PVs in current year?

Comment: You don't have to all() when you are using filter(). I removed that part form edit.

Comment: I have edited the query to get the PVs from current year.

Answer (score 0):

@sandeep your query was not displaying anything on the template so i first queried out all the users

## VIew.py

```
 from django.db.models import Count, Q 
 import datetime
  qry = User.objects.all()
```

i then filtered the query with your code

```
qryr = qry.filter(Q(create__isnull=False)\ &
                       Q(create__created__year=today.year))\
                       .annotate(counter=Count('create'))\
                       .prefetch_related('create').order_by('-counter')
```

and here is my template

## template.html

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
             <thead>
               <tr>
                 <th scope="col">Users</th>
                 <th scope="col">Pv's Recorded</th>


               </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                {% for i in qryr %}
                 
               <tr>
                   <td>{{i.first_name}} {{i.last_name}}</td>
                   <td> {{ i.counter }}</td>
               </tr>
               {% endfor %}
             </tbody>
           </table>
```

thank you very much

Comment: you can remove this condition "{% if i.counter.count != 0 %}". You have filtered the query in veiws here (create__isnull=False). It will work same

Comment: And you don't have to use all() if you are using filter(). I must have missed something. but this will work.